# React Native PermissionsAndroid - Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to request bluetooth permissions on Android M (API 23) during runtime using [PermissionsAndroid](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.43/docs/permissionsandroid.html#permissionsandroid) from `react-native`.

I get the following error `Tried to use permissions API but the host Activity doesn't implement PermissionAwareActivity`. Any ideas as to how I can fix this error?

My code is

**Bluetooth.js:**

```
componentWillMount() {
    ...
    this.checkAndGrantPermissions();
}
async checkAndGrantPermissions() {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.LOCATION,
      {
        title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        message: 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
                   'so you can take awesome pictures.'
      });
}
```

I also tried doing this:

```
async checkAndGrantPermissions() {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.LOCATION,
        {
        title: 'Cool Photo App Camera Permission',
        message: 'Cool Photo App needs access to your camera ' +
        'so you can take awesome pictures.'
        }
    ).then(() => {

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

But then I get this error:

`{"framesToPop":1,"code":"E_INVALID_ACTIVITY","line":8001,"column":29,"sourceURL":"http://packager.xb-kvy.darkwata.pentaheliosapp.exp.direct:80/main.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false"}`

Comment: Not familiar with React native, but just implement PermissionAwareActivity

Comment: @LunarWatcher From my understanding `react-native` should be implementing that already.